# how can i change the style of scroll bar

Tags: asp.net, css, scrollbar

I have a css code likes

```
  .scrollPanel
    {
        height: 100px;
        width: auto;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
```

You can see my example [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nvwUL/) !
What I want to know is how to change the style of scroll bar ?
How can I set css style to it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now there's no cross browser solution to change the scroll bars with CSS ONLY, alternatively you can use [jQuery](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html) to style them.

Solution for webkit browsers only

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GDhJc/)

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

[Credits](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

Comment: jQuery custom content scroller is useful for me :) Thanks Mr.Alien !

Answer (score 0):

You can complete the webkit solution from Mr. Alien with the styling elements for IE too, but just the colors so far I know. 
[Here is the documentation about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974092%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

As its said before, there are no CSS only solution for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```css
   /* Hide scrollbar buttons */
   ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
       display: none;
   }

   /* Style the scrollbar */
   ::-webkit-scrollbar {
       width: 5px;
   }

   /* Track styles */
   ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
       background: #f1f1f1; /* Color of the track */
       border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners */
   }

   /* Handle styles */
   ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
       background: #888; /* Color of the handle */
       border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners */
   }

       /* Handle hover styles */
       ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
           background: #555; /* Color of the handle on hover */
       }
```